# connection of c# application to server using integrated security

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I want to connect my application to server using windows authentication,
currently i am using this connection string which is placed in settings of my app.

```
server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user; password=Pass
```

I know i have to use integrated security true but what actually i have to do with SQL SERVER.
I have the access to remote server.
Do i have to change settings of sql server

I have tried creating a new user in sql server with windows authentication
Is it should be application specific

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: connect to server with windows authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a "Login" under the server's "Security" node for the Windows user (or group the user is in) and give that login access to the database you want.

All of that can be done in the new login screen.

Comment: how can i create this by sql query

Comment: @ankur, you'll need to run [`CREATE LOGIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) to create the server login and then couple that with [`sp_adduser`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181422.aspx) to create the user for the database you want access to.

Comment: created a login as you told but it didnt allow me to connect through my server its saying unauthorize access

Comment: @ankur, did you create the user too? And when you created the user, did you specify that you wanted `dbo` access to the specific database?